# How to manually servce a .cshtml file without a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webpages

Is it possible to create a .cshtml file (Razor) and process it manually?  I would like to link to a page that does not currently have a controller, yet display a .cshtml page as a result.  How would this be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if its what you need, but Microsoft recently added something like this to the ASP.Net product line where you could use just Razor marked up web pages, and funnily enough they called it ASP.Net Web Pages.

http://www.asp.net/web-pages